# Using a dynamic <script> (a <script> appended to the DOM by JavaScript) to load and initialize Clicky Web Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, analytics

I'm creating an HTML/JavaScript widget to be used on third-party sites. This widget is generated by a <script> that our customers will insert on their page. The <script> creates an <iframe> in the customer's domain, and then creates and inserts all of that <iframe>'s content using JavaScript.

It's important that this <iframe> contain Clicky's tracking code to monitor clicks on outbound links. Unfortunately, I'm not having any luck getting Clicky to work when I append the requisite <script> elements to the <iframe> using JavaScript.

I first tried simply appending the Clicky tracking code to the <iframe> after appending some test outbound links, hoping that Clicky could attach to those automatically as it does on a static page. That didn't seem to work, so my next inclination was to use the "advanced_disable" custom option and use clicky.log() on the links I want to track. Here's a link to a test page that's along those lines:

http://onespot.wsj.com/static/clicky_iframe_test.html

When clicking a link on that test page, the action is not logged in Clicky, and a JavaScript error appears:

```
clicky is not defined
```

This ("clicky") appears to be defined in http://static.getclicky.com/js, which I confirmed through the Firebug console is indeed loading before I click a test outbound link.

Has anyone successfully loaded Clicky in this way? If so, could you provide some sample code, a link to a working implementation, or some feedback on what's wrong with my code? I would also be interested to know if this is even possible.

Thanks very much for any help or advice!

Comment: Are you appending to the iframe element or to the document within the iframe element?

Comment: I'm appending to the document object within the <iframe> using jQuery similar to this: $('iframe').contents().find('body').append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">...</scr' + 'ipt>');

Comment: OK, well that's good at least.  So I presume you can tell whether your script is being successfully loaded (like, you can drop an "alert" or "console.log" in there and see that it's being loaded and run by the browser).  If I understand correctly, this script finds <a> tags and modifies them so that they call through some tracking mechanism; is that right?  That error about "clicky" not being defined; what throws that?  Is that produced by the code wrapped around the <a> tags by the script itself?  Can you tell with a debugger if "clicky" is there in the window object?

Answer (score 0):

This got debugged further to morph into this question: [Why does appending a <script> to a dynamically created <iframe> seem to run the script in the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the-s)