# Why does appending a <script> to a dynamically created <iframe> seem to run the script in the parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, iframe, parent

I'm attempting to create an <iframe> using JavaScript, then append a <script> element to that <iframe>, which I want to run in the context of the <iframe>d document.

Unfortunately, it seems I'm doing something wrong - my JavaScript appears to execute successfully, but the context of the <script> is the parent page, not the <iframe>d document. I also get a 301 Error in Firebug's "Net" tab when the browser requests **iframe_test.js**, though it then requests it again (not sure why?) successfully.

This is the code I'm using (live demo at http://onespot.wsj.com/static/iframe_test.html):

**iframe_test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>&lt;iframe&gt; test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bucket"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bucket').append('<iframe id="test"></iframe>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          var iframe_body = $('#test').contents().find('body');
          iframe_body.append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://onespot.wsj.com/static/iframe_test.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
        }, 100);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**iframe_test.js**

```
$(function() {
  var test = '<p>Shouldn\'t this be inside the &lt;iframe&gt;?</p>';
  $('body').append(test);
});
```

One thing that seems unusual is that the the code in **iframe_test.js** even works; I haven't loaded jQuery in the <iframe> itself, only in the parent document. That seems like a clue to me, but I can't figure out what it means.

Any ideas, suggestions, etc. would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that the <script> element itself is constructed in your parent document.  Have you tried adding a script block to the child document that, when executed, sets its "src" attribute to the actual file you want to load?

Comment: This is by-design in order to prevent cross site scripting.  If you could inject script into another site in the fashion you're attempting you could inject script from any iframe container to any website without issue.

Comment: Well, I'd think that the "same domain" rules would prevent the addition of any content at all to the document in the iframe. If the document is from the same domain, however, the rules don't apply.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks very much for your input. Your idea sounds like it could work - I gave it a try but couldn't make it work (though that doesn't mean it's not a valid solution). I ended up going with the code in my answer below, which is a more elegant solution for my purposes.

Comment: @Nissan Fan - Thanks for the feedback. However, Pointy is correct - since this <iframe> is created in the same domain as the parent page, each has access to the other's DOM. You're absolutely right about an <iframe> that lives in a different domain than the parent page, though.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Had the same problem, took me hours to find the solution.
You just need to create the script's object using the **iframe's document**.

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById("myIframeId");
var script = myIframe.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = src;
myIframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Awesome... was working on same thing from hours... got it fixed now

Comment: @user2284570 Is there a way to do this cross-domain?

Comment: @StanJames : Dunno,  but that would typically lead to cross AJAX without ᴄᴏʀꜱ.

Comment: @StanJames cross domain iframes are totally different ball game. Even if there was a solution, the browsers will path them pretty soon. It's a security feature to prevent bad guys hack your bank passwords and so on.

Comment: btw, I suggest using this for the content window, for the sake of browser compatibility: `var doc = iframe.contentDocument ?
    iframe.contentDocument :
    (iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.document);`

Answer (score 16):

I didn't find an answer to my original question, but I did find another approach that works even better (at least for my purposes).

This doesn't use jQuery on the parent page (which is actually a good thing, as I'd prefer not to load it there), but it does load jQuery in the <iframe> in an apparently completely valid and usable way. All I'm doing is writing over the <iframe>'s document object with a new one created from scratch. This allows me to simply include a <script> element in a string which I then write to the <iframe>'s document object.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>frame</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="test"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // create a new <iframe> element
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

      // append the new element to the <div id="bucket"></div>
      var bucket = document.getElementById('test');
      bucket.appendChild(iframe);

      // create a string to use as a new document object
      var val = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';
      val += '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("body").append("<h1>It works!</h1>"); }); </scr' + 'ipt>';

      // get a handle on the <iframe>d document (in a cross-browser way)
      var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
      if (doc.document) {
        doc = doc.document;
      }

      // open, write content to, and close the document
      doc.open();
      doc.write(val);
      doc.close();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps someone down the road!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Is there any way to APPEND to the iframe so the body contents are not erased?

Comment: Why writing`'<scr' + 'ipt`instead of`'<script`directly ?

Comment: @user2284570: Browsers will interpret any HTML strings within inline `<script>` tags literally, so something like `var endScript = '</script>';` would be interpreted as a premature closing tag for the current script, resulting in a syntax error.

Comment: really helps when pasting a whole html content containing script tag inside an iframe

Comment: but this has disadvantage as `doc.write` starts writing only when the whole page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question is simple - the execution of the script is done by jquery, and since jquery is loaded in the top frame, this is where the script runs too, no matter where you are appending it. A smarter implementation of jquery can no doubt be made to use the correct window object, but for now things are how they are.

As to the workarounds, you already have two good answers (even if one is your own). What I might add is that you can use one of those workarounds to include jquery.js in the iframe, and then get that jquery object instead of the top one to insert your additional markup... but that may very well be overkill too.