# jQuery add iFrame with content

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I've such a problem.
I need to open iframe in fancybox (I require iframe because I need to browse through links in the opened document and stay in fancybox),
but I want to put content into iframe from variable, not through src attribute (I've already got content by AJAX (I need to do some checks on content before putting it to iframe, so there are no way to do it instead of AJAX query), so I do not need one more query).

Fancybox does not allow to use 'content' attribute with 'type':'iframe'. So I decided to create iframe dynamically, insert my content into it, and show iframe by fancybox as a regular block.

It's like

```
jQuery('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('body').contents().find('body').append(content);
```

And than

```
jQuery('<iframe id="someId"/>').fancybox();
```

But the first part does not work. I can see the iframe that was added to page but without any content (I have full HTML page in variable content, but when I try to append just some text it doesn't work as well).

What I've done wrong?

Maybe there is another way to do what I need?

Comment: Had the same problem, could you please tell me if you fixed the above issue @krasilich

Answer (score 18):

your problem will be solve after calling jquery's ready method like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('body');
$('#someId').contents().find('body').append('<b>hello sajjad</b>');
});
</script>

<iframe id="someId"></iframe>
```

Comment: Related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you split that line in two:

```
jQuery('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('body');
jQuery('#someId').contents().find('body').append(content);
```

Then change your selector to be correct, before it was creating a new iframe, not inserting it in the DOM and the calling fancybox on it, however this should work:

```
jQuery('#someId').fancybox();
```

Comment: I can see empty iframe in the bottom of my page. I put in content simple text (var content = 'Text in Iframe'). And there are no errors in firebug. Element body in iFrame is empty

Comment: @krasilich Have you tried the code I suggested? I have edited my answer with a new discovery.

Comment: var content = 'Text in iframe';
jQuery('<iframe id="someId"/>').appendTo('body')
jQuery('#someId').contents().find('body').append(content);
jQuery('#someId').fancybox();
That's what I run in firebug console

Comment: Fantastic! What happened. It seems like there may be other problems involved. Test if jQuery is available by simply executing the line `jQuery` in firebug, if available if should return a function.

Comment: And this is what happened http://img232.imageshack.us/f/screenshotylj.png/
So, jQuery works fine because of that create iframe and appnd it to body. But Body of iframe still without content

Comment: You are not explicitly creating the HTML tags inside of the iframe. So maybe firebug is giving the illusion of tags, whereas jQuery does not see them. Try creating the tags inside of the iframe when you create (modifying line one of my answer).

Comment: but jQuery('#someId').contents().find('body') return an element

Comment: OK, then I have no more ideas. It is either another hidden problem, or I may have got something wrong. If I were you I would create a simplified test case and see what happens there.

Answer (score 2):

Has passed time of this question, but here is another solution:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
ifrm.id = "someId"; // optional id
ifrm.onload = function() {
    // optional onload behaviour
}
setTimeout(function() {
    $(ifrm).contents().find("body").html(content);
}, 1);
```