# dynamically build iframe with script that calls rss feed

Tags: javascript, iframe, build, rss

I am working on a project where I am building an iframe and filling it with html code to display an rss feed. The code below shows how I am accomplishing this. It works fine in firefox but when I run the function in internet explorer it doesn't load the rss feed. any ideas?

JavaScript Function

```
 function AddIframe()
    {           
        ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("name", "iFrame1");
        ifrm.setAttribute("id","iFrame1");
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument; 
        ifrm.document.open(); 
        ifrm.document.write("<html><head><title>testIframe</title></head><body><div> <script language='JavaScript' src='http://itde.vccs.edu/rss2js/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nfl.com%2Frss%2Frsslanding%3FsearchString%3Dhome&chan=n&num=20&desc=1&date=y&targ=y' type='text/javascript'>" + String.fromCharCode(60).toString() + "/script> </div></body></html>");     
        ifrm.document.close();                  
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div>
      <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="AddIframe();" />
 </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614850/jquery-add-iframe-with-content

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  After peeking at your JavaScript, I see that my original observation is a red herring (though it still looks like trouble to me).  I try to avoid `document.write()`.  Some better options:

- Append the elements to the DOM instead of `document.write()`.
- Better yet, rather than outputting JavaScript that outputs HTML from php, just directly output HTML from php, and set the iframe src to your php page directly.

---

**Original answer:**

These lines look suspicious:

```
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;  
ifrm.document.open();
```

Only if `ifrm.contentWindow` exists will the following line work.  Looking and the second conditional, we know that if it fails there is no `ifrm.contentDocument.document` and the following line won't work.  If the second conditional passes, it seems unlikely that there is an `ifrm.contentDocument.document.document` property.

---

By the way, that double ternary expression could be made more concise:

```
ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;
```

The point is moot however, because of the issues stated above.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use jQuery and the .append() function and have a seperate page to the heaving lifting?

eg. $(this).append('');

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out, when writing to the iframe, internet explorer is more picky about the syntax than firefox so I had to use some escapes to get it working. Also I changed the code so now it accepts a rss URL and adds it on button click. please see code below.

JavaScript

```
 function AddIframe(url)
    {
        try{
        var SelectedFeed = url;             
        var semiUrl = "src=" + replaceSpecial(SelectedFeed); + "&chan=n&num=20&desc=1&date=y&targ=y";
        var source = 'src=\"http://itde.vccs.edu/rss2js/feed2js.php?' + semiUrl + '\"';  

        var htmlWriter = "<html><head><title>testIframe</title><link rel='stylesheet' href='gadget.css' /></head><body><div>" + '<scr'+'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" ' + source +'></scr'+'ipt>' + "</div></body></html>"                       

        ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("name", "iFrame1");
        ifrm.setAttribute("id","iFrame1");
        document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(ifrm);
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.      contentDocument; 
        ifrm.document.open(); 
        ifrm.document.write(htmlWriter);
        ifrm.document.close();  

        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }

    }

 function replaceSpecial(Text)
    {
        try{        
            var r1 = Text;
            r1 = r1.replace(/ /g,"%20");
            r1 = r1.replace(/@/g,"%40");
            r1 = r1.replace(/#/g,"%23");
            r1 = r1.replace(/\$/g,"%24");               
            r1 = r1.replace(/\%/g,"%25");
            r1 = r1.replace(/&/g,"%26");
            r1 = r1.replace(/=/g,"%3D");
            r1 = r1.replace(/\+/g,"%2B");
            r1 = r1.replace(/:/g,"%3A");
            r1 = r1.replace(/;/g,"%3B");                
            r1 = r1.replace(/"/g,"%22");                
            r1 = r1.replace(/\\/g,"%5C");
            r1 = r1.replace(/\//g,"%2F");
            r1 = r1.replace(/\?/g,"%3F");
            r1 = r1.replace(/</g,"%3C");
            r1 = r1.replace(/>/g,"%3E");
            r1 = r1.replace(/\[/g,"%5B");
            r1 = r1.replace(/]/g,"%5D");
            r1 = r1.replace(/{/g,"%7B");
            r1 = r1.replace(/}/g,"%7D");
            r1 = r1.replace(/`/g,"%60");                

            Text = r1;

            return Text;                    
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }

    }
```

HTML

```
  <input type="button" value="Add Sports" onclick="AddIframe('http://www.nfl.com/rss/rsslanding?searchString=home');" />
  <input type="button" value="Add News" onclick="AddIframe('http://msn.com/rss/news.aspx');" />
```