# convert html text to jquery object

Tags: jquery, html

I would need to transform text to html jquery object, so that I had an access to the values specified in the  and the following example.

```
var htmlContent = '<!doctype><html><head><title>Lorem Ipsum</title>Other code</head><body><div id="content"><h1>Custom code</h1><h2>Highlight2</h2></div></body></html>';
```

I want to modify so that I could work with HTML content in jquery follows

```
htmlContent.find('head title').text();
```

to `h1` and `h2` know approaches, probably because they are not vnotrene tags in `<div id="content"></div>`

Currently I have the following code:

```
var htmlContent = $(htmlContent);
```

But it does not work properly.

Thank you for counseling.

Comment: can easily  done using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: $('title') will grab the title tag....

Comment: looks like an XY problem. why would you need to store an entire page's html in a jQuery object unless its the page you are working on? please tell us what you are trying to do, maybe there is an easier way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose next:

```
var htmlContent = '<!doctype><html><head><title>Lorem Ipsum</title>Other code</head><body>Custom code</body></html>';

// use temporary iframe
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentDocument.write(htmlContent);

// get <title> content; next should work in IE8 too
var titleText = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('head title').innerHTML;
console.log(titleText);

// remove temporary iframe element
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
```

Note: I've changed `.textContent` to `.innerHTML` for IE8 support.

Alternative way, using jQuery:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe>').appendTo('body');
iframe[0].contentDocument.write(htmlContent);
var titleText = $('head title', iframe[0].contentDocument).text();
console.log(titleText);
iframe.remove();
```

Comment: it works for the tag title, but if I edit it so that I want info on the body tag so it no longer working.

Comment: It's strage... I tried next code in FF and Chrome and it works: `$('body', iframe[0].contentDocument).text();` (well, actually you should remove `Other code` from `<head>`, it should not be there)

Comment: This is the entire contents of the html page, which is obtained by using `$.ajax` function. And when I have `$('body',iframe[0] .contentDocument).text();` return empty string (Google Chrome)

Comment: Could you create some pastebin or codepen to show the problem? Or just debug your AJAX response content - is everything ok with that HTML?

Comment: My ajax code: `var $jOk = jQuery.noConflict();

$jOk.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
        success: function (text, status, request) {

    var iframe = $jOk('<iframe>').appendTo('body');
    iframe[0].contentDocument.write(text);
    var titleText = $jOk('body', iframe[0].contentDocument).text();
    console.log(titleText);
    iframe.remove();
}` but in console log is empty string. html is the complete code from the `<!DOCTYPE>` after `</html>`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you provide full HTML example? (in PasteBin, I guess)

Comment: Here is a basic html where use in my code. I modified the file path.
[link]{http://pastebin.com/1abHWHPw}

Comment: Still strange :) I tested your example HTML, it appends to iframe and `.text()` returns non empty string. You should carefully debug your code. Set necessary breakpoints, check what is the AJAX response inside AJAX callback, step line by line and check where it goes wrong

Comment: One thing that may cause problem (and solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614850/jquery-add-iframe-with-content

Answer (score 1):

Your code seem ok, this is the way how to create new elements in jQuery, eg.:

```
var $a = $('<div id="main"><p><strong>hello</strong><p></div>');

$a.find('p strong').text();

-> "hello"
```

I think the problem is with the html/head tags instead, jQuery ignores them, but I guess you don't need the whole html block anyway:

```
$('<html><head><div></head></html>');

-> [<div>​</div>​]
```

If you are parsing a string that contains a complete html I'd recommend using `jQuery.parseHTML()`, or if you need the body node too, you can use documentFragments or iframe, in this case there's no problem with `<html>` nodes.

```
var htmltext = "<html><div><p>test</p></div></hmtl>"
$('<div>').append($.parseHTML(htmltext)).find('p').text()

-> "test"
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

Answer (score 0):

`$(htmlContent)` will give you following

```
Object[title, <TextNode textContent="Other codeCustom code">]
```

Now you can use `$(htmlContent)[0].text` to get title value

Answer (score 0):

Try This way.

```
$(htmlContent).filter('title').text()
$(htmlContent).filter('head').text()
```

Comment: I want to notice that this way is a bit unpredicted and dangerous. Title (surprisely) works correct, but `$(htmlContent).filter('head').text()` returns wrong value. And you can't get the `<body>` content, only `<title>`. You shouldn't trust this approach

Comment: No offence, I'm just not sure that this solution is stable and cross-browser

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns me an empty string. it does not work as I need (use browser Chrome)