# Using Yahoo Web Analytics in jsRender web site

Tags: jquery, jsrender, yahoo-analytics

In my web site I'm only using client-side scripting (jsrender and jquery) for presenting data. I'm only presenting data from a json-feed, so there have been no need (until now??) for a full scale web-app.

Now I'm trying to integrate Yahoo Web Analytics (YWA). In the search result page, I try to capture the querystring and total hits from the json-feed into the YWA javascripts, but this is quite diffifcult as I'm trying to print client-side jsrender variables into client-side YWA variables:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d.yimg.com/mi/eu/ywa.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    /*globals YWA*/
    var YWATracker = YWA.getTracker("1000918585199");
    var ACTION='INTERNAL_SEARCH';
    var _S_ISK={{=querystring}};
    var _S_ISR={{=totalHits}};
    YWATracker.setCF(01, 'Search-Results'); 
    YWATracker.setCF(04, 'no');
    YWATracker.setCF(06, 'KAW');
    YWATracker.setDocumentName("Result Page");
    YWATracker.setDocumentGroup("KAW");
    YWATracker.submit();
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <div><img src="http://s.analytics.yahoo.com/p.pl?a=1000918585199&js=no" width="1"     height="1" alt="" /></div>
   </noscript>
```

And this is not working. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to append the script tags to the html:

```
$("#statistics").append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">var YWATracker = YWA.getTracker("1000918585199");var ACTION="INTERNAL_SEARCH"; var _S_ISK="' + querystring + '"; var _S_ISR=' + totalHits + ';YWATracker.setCF(01, "Search-Results");YWATracker.setCF(04, "no");YWATracker.setCF(06, "KAW");YWATracker.setDocumentName("Result Page");YWATracker.setDocumentGroup("KAW");YWATracker.submit();</scr' + 'ipt>');
```

This gave me a good idea on how to solve it: [Why does appending a <script> to a dynamically created <iframe> seem to run the script in the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the)