# Cannot Add Script tag to Iframe Head or Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to add `<script></script>` tag to an `iframe` head or body but not able to succeed.

```
var iframe = $("iframe#demo),
    contents = iframe.contents(),
    body = contents.find('body');
```

Attempt one:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
$(body).append(script);
```

Second attempt:

```
$("`<script></script>`").appendTo(contents.find('head'))
```

Either of the method above does not work for me.

Let me know if anyone has some pointer.

Thanks

Viral

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the

Comment: I saw that...but the problem is when I used it standalone like in the post u gave it works fine. but when I use jquery it does not work. However, quick question Do I need to write all the html,body,head tag inside iframe?