# Move DOM Node to Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, popup

I am trying to move a DOM node from the "root" page to a new pop-up that is created via `window.open()`. Here is the code I am using.

```
var win = window.open('/Search/Print', 'printSearchResults'),
    table = $('#printTable');
win.document.close();
setTimeout(function () {
    var el = win.document.createElement("table");
    el.innerHTML = table.html();
    win.document.body.appendChild(el);
}, 40);
```

It works in Chrome, but in IE8, I receive the following error: "Unknown runtime error."

I've also tried it this way:

```
var p = window.open('/Search/Print', 'printSearchResults'),
    table = $('#printTable');
setTimeout(function () {
    p.document.body.appendChild(table.clone(false)[0]);
}, 100);
```

Doing it this way, I receive "No such interface supported" in IE8. Again, Chrome works fine.

Does anyone have a way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Here is the HTML for the pop-up window just for the sake of completeness:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Print Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but arbitrary `setTimeout()` calls are a really bad way of dealing with an async load. Try using an `onload` handler for your new window instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on IE9 ( and IE8/7 browser mode).

Instead of `el.innerHTML = table.html();`

using jquery `$(el).html(table.html());` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use iframes and new windows, you should initialise them with addres: about:blank, before you write() to them. Also note that loading/opening the window/frame takes time, so you cannot write to them at right away. set a timeout, or check onload. 
Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731778/588079) for more info.

Good luck!