# How to add a javascript function inside the body of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have a html file with iframe and button in it, Is there a way to add a javascript function inside the body of iframe after I click the button?. Here is my code. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function callMe() { 
            var frame = $('iframe'),
            contents = frame.contents(),
            body = contents.find('body');

    var script2   = document.createElement("script");
    script2.type  = "text/javascript";
    script2.text  = " function setEmployeeId(){var employeeId = 0;};"            
    $(body).append(script2);
        };      
    </script>



    <title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
        <iframe src="page2.html">           
        </iframe>
    <button onClick="callMe();">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I want is to be like this.

```
<html>
<head>  

    <title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
        <iframe>
<html>
<head>  
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
function setemployeeId() {
var employeeId = 0;
};
</script>
</body>
</html> 
</iframe>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the frame's page on your domain?

Comment: @AndrewBarber i'd assume so considering the `src` is relative "page2.html".

Comment: You may find your answer here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you can clarify a few things for me as we go, but I think I have some bad news for you.

Any content that is loaded in an `iframe` cannot truly edited unless you own the page that is being loaded, in that case you can just bake in whatever you need into the loaded page.

HOWEVER!

You can still access elements in the iframe by using the contentWindow attribute. That is all laid out for you here: [How to pick element inside iframe using document.getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451358/how-to-pick-element-inside-iframe-using-document-getelementbyid)

Once you've got the element you want to work with, you can create a function in the parent window and then add a call to the parent window's function using `window.parent`. That's outlined here: [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

So if you wanted to make a button in an `iframe` alter the contents of the `iframe` you could use

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('myButton')
```

and then create a function in your parent window

```
function changeIt(){
    document.getElementById('thingToChangeInIframe_ItsIDintheIframe').property = 'value';
}
```

and append it to the button with the code

```
elem.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeIt();');
```

If you have any clarifications to what you need just comment and we'll work those out. I'm sorry this doesn't use much jQuery but that's not really my forte, but I think the pure javascript is relatively self explanatory.

EDIT: I should clarify that if the iframe is on another domain then your options are pretty much all eliminated. For security reasons you can't mess with the settings on other people's pages when you load them in an iframe.

Comment: For cross-browser support it's still a good idea to use `var y=(x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y=y.document;` as seen on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp)