# How to use jQuery methods inside an iframe context

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I couldn't find how to do this after digging through S\O. Im using javascript to create an iframe and then i'm loading jQuery into the Iframe. Now I just want to call methods such as $ajax in the Iframe context.
Below is how i did it.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name = "loginFrame";
iframe.id = "loginFrame";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var idocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var jq = idocument.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
idocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(jq);
jq.onload = function () {
}
```

This works and `idocument` will in fact have the jQuery script in its body. Now using the Iframe, how would I make calls using jQuery?

```
idocument.$.ajax(url, settings)
```

Does not work and returns 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined` error. Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: No real need to inject jQuery into iframe if you have it in main window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** For the following method to work properly the iframe src cannot point to a different domain, and **must be set**, for example

```
iframe.src = "about:blank"
```

The jquery "**$**" is an attribute of the **window object of the iframe.**

So you can access jquery using

```
iframe.contentWindow.window.$
```

If you wanted to make an ajax call you would do:

```
iframe.contentWindow.window.$.ajax(url, settings)
```

Also if you want to use Jquery the normal way you can do

```
$ = iframe.contentWindow.window.jQuery
```

**Note:** This should be in jq.onload and this will conflict with jQuery if it is on the main page so you could instead do:

```
iframe.$ = iframe.contentWindow.window.jQuery
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for some reason I'm getting "$ is not a function"

Comment: Did you run this in a browser console? I'm not sure but I think this is what causes the error.

Comment: I'm just getting same error either in console or browser. Initially I thought it could be that jquery library is added asynchronously but it doesn't explain why it fails in console. Have you tried to run your code?

Comment: this is what I tried so far:  iframe.contentWindow.window.$('body').append('this does not work');
        iframe.contentWindow.window.document.write('this works');

Comment: Yeah, that's what i just tried and your right, I think i'll remove it from my answer. Thanks!

Comment: ifram.src = "#" fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? `iframe.contentWindow.$.ajax(url, settings)`

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me using a method from another SO solution:

[Stackoverflow] [Why does appending a <script> to a dynamically created <iframe> seem to run the script in the parent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the)

First 3 lines of your code then:

```
 //* Updated to use the 2.1.4 jquery...(and tested still works!)
 // create a string to use as a new document object
var val = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';

//If you want to add further script tags un-comment:
//val += '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("body").append("<h1>It works!</h1>"); }); </scr' + 'ipt>';

// get a handle on the <iframe>d document (in a cross-browser way)
var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) {
doc = doc.document;
}

// open, write content to, and close the document
doc.open();
doc.write(val);
doc.close();

//Assuming this is the first script tag in the iframe...
doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].onload = function () {

//* necessary for cross-browser function have to get the original document context:
var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;

//Edited to initialize $ not in global namespace yet:
// to scope the jQuery's $ to the iframe...
var $ = doc.$;
//Finally you can use jQuery to do ajax
$.ajax({ });
}
```

Out of curiosity why can you not give the parent window access to jQuery?
Something to do with security issues?