# Load a page in a detached element and execute its scripts on itself without affecting the current document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently attempting to do the following when the user clicks on a link:

1. The click is caught and, instead of navigating to the URL, the URL is loaded into a jQuery object.
2. I take the `<article>` element in the jQuery object.
3. I replace the `<article>` element in the current document with the  element in the jQuery object.

This works fine, except that the scripts in the page that I load in the jQuery object are not executed. Those scripts must run for its content to be complete and to work.

Normally, I would just load the scripts using jQuery's getScript function after replacing the `<article>` element, except this has some undesirable effects on everything in the page that is outside of the `<article>` element, because those scripts are not meant to be executed twice.

I am working with an extremely limited framework, which is not really suited for web development, and I am stuck with it. It generates a huge minimized single module. I cannot simply compartment or edit the scripts to make them do exactly what I need them to do, and none of its functions seem to do exactly what I need it to do.

```
function loadArticle(targetURL)
{
  var newPage = $("<div />");
  newPage.load(targetURL, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status != "error")
    {
      newPageScripts = $('<script src="path/to/framework/script.js"></script>');
      newPageArticle = newPage.find("article");

      $("article").replaceWith(newPageArticle);
      $("article").append(newPageScripts);
      window.history.pushState("","",targetURL);  
    } 
  });
}
```

I am wondering if I can, either:

1. Load the page in an object, force it to execute its own scripts on itself, then replace the `<article>` element in my document with its resulting `<article>` element.
2. Load the page in an object, replace the `<article>` element in my document with its `<article>` element, then run its scripts, in a way that only affects the content of the `<article>` element, as if it was restricted to its scope, or sandboxed.

Comment: Did you considered iframe element? In that case make sure that you are creating [script in iframe's document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591135/why-does-appending-a-script-to-a-dynamically-created-iframe-seem-to-run-the).

Comment: @bigless So something like that, then? https://jsfiddle.net/bluewoods/pq9cw7dx/

Comment: @bigless For the record, I tried using a similar approach on my website, and unfortunately, it creates significant performance problems. Also, I can't unload the frame after taking its `<article>` out of the frame and into the main document without unloading its javascript at the same time, and then the article stops working.

What I can do however is replace `<article>` with an iframe that loads the page, then remove everything but the article inside the iframe. That's the most amateurish, hacky approach I can think of, but it's the only one that seems to work in this context...